# Why so much Android Studio launcher icon padding?

Tags: android, android-studio

The Android design guidelines state that a launcher icon should be 48dp across, with 1dp padding within that on each side, meaning the actual icon is 46dp in size (assuming a square icon). https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons

But when I use the launcher icon creation tool in Android Studio (from an image) it creates an icon with much more padding than that (it is not coming from the source image). For example my mipmap-xxxhdpi asset is 192x192px as expected, but excluding the padding Android Studio added the icon is only 160x164px, equivalent to 40dp, not 48dp.

It looks to me that Android Studio is failing to adopt the Android design guidelines regarding launcher icons, and adding substantially more padding than is needed, but I am posting here in case I'm missing something.

Update, added an example showing the expansive padding.

[image: Icon]

Comment: Good question. I was also trying to generate an icon using the online tool: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html and was wondering the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say, I tried that older tool too, and it applies the too much padding too. So much has changed with Android it's hard to remember how things were. It looks like launcher icons used to have lots more padding than they do now and Android Studio needs updating. I might log this as an IDE issue.